# Query to find out the exact last hour data in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want the average data from the last hour in short if the current time is 2:30, the query should return the data from 1:00 to 2:00 and the average of 1:00 to 2:00 (which will be only one value (not changing).

```
time            data       Avg_data (There should be one output)
1/2/2022 1:01   1.2          1.5416
1/2/2022 1:02   1.3
1/2/2022 1:03   1.4
1/2/2022 1:04   1.1
1/2/2022 1:05   1.2
1/2/2022 1:07   1.2
1/2/2022 1:08   1.5
1/2/2022 1:09   1.7
1/2/2022 1:10   1.6
1/2/2022 1:11   1.5
1/2/2022 1:12   1.4
1/2/2022 1:13   1.8
1/2/2022 1:14   1.8
1/2/2022 1:15   1.8
1/2/2022 1:16   2.1
1/2/2022 1:17   2.9
1/2/2022 1:21   1.8
1/2/2022 1:22   1.9
1/2/2022 1:23   1.8
1/2/2022 1:24   1.5
1/2/2022 1:25   1.6
1/2/2022 1:26   1.6
1/2/2022 1:27   1.5
1/2/2022 1:28   1.5
1/2/2022 1:29   1.5
1/2/2022 1:30   1.3
1/2/2022 1:31   1.3
1/2/2022 1:32   1.4
1/2/2022 1:33   1.7
1/2/2022 1:34   1.8
1/2/2022 1:35   1.7
1/2/2022 1:36   1.5
1/2/2022 1:37   1.6
1/2/2022 1:38   1.3
1/2/2022 1:39   1.4
1/2/2022 1:43   1.7
1/2/2022 1:44   1.3
1/2/2022 1:45   1.4
1/2/2022 1:46   1.4
1/2/2022 1:47   1.1
1/2/2022 1:48   1.3
1/2/2022 1:49   1.2
1/2/2022 1:50   1.4
1/2/2022 1:51   1.3
1/2/2022 1:52   1.5
1/2/2022 1:53   1.5
1/2/2022 1:57   1.4
1/2/2022 1:58   1.2
1/2/2022 1:59   1.4
1/2/2022 2:00   1.3
```

My query looks something like

```
SELECT time, avg(data)
FROM exercise 
WHERE  
time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour')
group by time,data;
```

Comment: The average of that data is not 45 though.  It doesn't even round to 45.

Comment: I just wrote it is an example.

Comment: It helps to post the create table scripts, then we can easily provide verifiable solutions.

Comment: It is important in examples that show the result of calculations that you get the calculations correct, yes it is just an example, but its hard for us to identify if your expectation requires some non-standard math-foo or if your issue was more general.  The standard average of the above dataset is 47.25, but if you are looking for the  _temporal mean_ for the whole hour, it would be closer to 46.883, time series analysis adds a new dimension. Without accurate figures it is hard for us to know what type of average you were expecting. In such a simple example we ask for your best effort ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is your `GROUP BY` statement. `time` is unique across all values, but so is `time` combined with `data`. The group needs to specify the common value that all items in the group share. We can do that by truncating the time to the hour, then group by that.

The following shows the averages for just the last full hour:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', time) as Hour, avg(data) as Avg
FROM exercise 
WHERE time >= date_trunc('hour', now()) - INTERVAL '1 hour'
  AND time < (date_trunc('hour', now()))
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', time);
```

For all hours except the current partial hour just use this filter:

```
WHERE time < (date_trunc('hour', now()))
```

## UPDATE:

**The data example from OP has changed significantly.
The following fiddle demonstrates a fictious example dataset that is used for the explanation that follows:**
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rqZ5rsgKFJBKufPsxmFzFX/3

#### Query #1

Show the averages of the data values for each hour of the day. We are using `DATE_TRUNC` to group the readings and compute the average, this implementation will consider the following arbitrary groupings:

- Group 01:00:
  01:00, 01:01, 01:59
- Group 02:00:
  02:00, 02:01, 02:59

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', time) as Hour, avg(data) as Avg
FROM exercise 
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', time);
```

| hour | avg |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1.2999999999999998 |
| 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.275 |

To filter this to only the most recent completed hour, so like the original post:

> if the current time is 2:30, ...return the average of 1:00 to 2:00

Then the following `WHERE` clause can be used 9as was shown above:

```
WHERE time >= date_trunc('hour', now()) - INTERVAL '1 hour'
  AND time < (date_trunc('hour', now()))
```

However to work with our current dataset, now() won't work and as PostgreSQL doesn't support variable declarations, it's out of scope to demonstrate further, if you ran that query, with the `WHERE` clause at `2022-01-26 2:30:00` then it would only return this:

| hour | avg |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |

> It is important to understand these basics before implementing window functions or joining back onto the original results

### Query #2

If you need the average in-line with the raw data, then we can join this result-set back onto the original query, or we can use a *Window Function*:

```
SELECT time
     , data
     , date_trunc('hour', time) as Hour
     , AVG  (data) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('hour', time)) as Avg
FROM exercise;
```

> **NOTE:**
> The *partition* value has been included in the output to make it visually obvious what value was used to group the records used in the window function.

| time | data | hour | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02T00:34:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1.2999999999999998 |
| 2022-01-02T00:59:59.999Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1.2999999999999998 |
| 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:01:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:03:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:08:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:09:00.000Z | 1.7 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:10:00.000Z | 1.6 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:11:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:13:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:14:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:15:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:17:00.000Z | 2.9 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:21:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:23:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:24:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:25:00.000Z | 1.6 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:31:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:32:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:33:00.000Z | 1.7 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:34:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:35:00.000Z | 1.7 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:36:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:39:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:43:00.000Z | 1.7 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:44:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:47:00.000Z | 1.1 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:50:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:51:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:53:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:57:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T01:58:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.57 |
| 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.275 |
| 2022-01-02T02:01:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.275 |
| 2022-01-02T02:02:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.275 |
| 2022-01-02T02:13:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.275 |
| 2022-01-02T02:24:00.000Z | 1.1 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.275 |
| 2022-01-02T02:25:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.275 |
| 2022-01-02T02:37:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.275 |
| 2022-01-02T02:38:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.275 |

*You can apply the same `WHERE` clause as previously stated to this query to limit the results to satisfy the original requirement:*

> if the current time is 2:30, the query should return the data from 1:00 to 2:00 and the average of 1:00 to 2:00

```
SELECT time
     , data
     , date_trunc('hour', time) as Hour
     , AVG  (data) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('hour', time)) as Avg
FROM exercise
WHERE time >= date_trunc('hour', now()) - INTERVAL '1 hour'
  AND time < (date_trunc('hour', now()));
```

### Query 3:

OP has asked a specific variation to this question in the comments:

> Is there a way to get average from 1:01 to 2:00?

To do that we simply *shift* the `time` value by one minute, but the core underlying query is the same, including the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT time
     , data
     , date_trunc('hour', time - interval '1 minute') as "Hr+1min"
     , AVG (data) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY (date_trunc('hour', time - interval '1 minute'))) as Avg
FROM exercise ;
```

| time | data | Hr+1min | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02T00:34:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1.3666666666666665 |
| 2022-01-02T00:59:59.999Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1.3666666666666665 |
| 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 1.3666666666666665 |
| 2022-01-02T01:01:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:03:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:08:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:09:00.000Z | 1.7 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:10:00.000Z | 1.6 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:11:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:13:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:14:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:15:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:17:00.000Z | 2.9 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:21:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:23:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:24:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:25:00.000Z | 1.6 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:31:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:32:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:33:00.000Z | 1.7 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:34:00.000Z | 1.8 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:35:00.000Z | 1.7 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:36:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:39:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:43:00.000Z | 1.7 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:44:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:47:00.000Z | 1.1 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:50:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:51:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:53:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:57:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T01:58:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T01:00:00.000Z | 1.5633333333333332 |
| 2022-01-02T02:01:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.2714285714285716 |
| 2022-01-02T02:02:00.000Z | 1.3 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.2714285714285716 |
| 2022-01-02T02:13:00.000Z | 1.4 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.2714285714285716 |
| 2022-01-02T02:24:00.000Z | 1.1 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.2714285714285716 |
| 2022-01-02T02:25:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.2714285714285716 |
| 2022-01-02T02:37:00.000Z | 1.2 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.2714285714285716 |
| 2022-01-02T02:38:00.000Z | 1.5 | 2022-01-02T02:00:00.000Z | 1.2714285714285716 |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rqZ5rsgKFJBKufPsxmFzFX/3)

Comment: Can you confirm to me if it query calculates from 1:01 to 2:00 ?

Comment: It calculates 1:00 - 1:59:59.9999, think of `Date_Trunc`  as a string manipulation that takes any timestamp and substitutes all elements _after_ the _datePart_ with **zeros**: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-date_trunc-function/ you initial attempt of `NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour' ` gives you the last hour, but not the last completed _hour of the day_

Comment: 01:00, 01:27, 01:59 => Date_Trunk => 01:00, but after that: 
02:00, 02:11 ...        => Date_Trunc => 02:00

Comment: I have added proper dataset for you to calculate, Is there a way to get average from 1:01 to 2:00 showing one value (1.5416: Average for that hour) for one hour. Make sure I have data for 2 months and still continuing for each minute. Is there a way to get the data for

Comment: Firstly, you should change you range, to [1:00, 2:00) that is greater than or equal to 1:00 and less than 2:00. That will simplify your expression and is a more natural type of analysis. Have a look at this fiddle that explains how it works without specifically filtering by a specific time: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rqZ5rsgKFJBKufPsxmFzFX/2

Comment: If the range 1:01 - 2:00 is important then have a look at this updated fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rqZ5rsgKFJBKufPsxmFzFX/3

Comment: I've updated my post with full explanations. If you need more assistance please view my profile or find me on [codementor.io](https://www.codementor.io/@chrisschaller?refer=badge)

Comment: I wrote the 3rd query with where including``` time < (date_trunc('hour', now())); ``` and other without where. The problem I am facing now is, I am getting multiple entry for example, you can see in column Hr+1min (3rd query). I want one entry for one hour that is for 1:00 it should be 1.5633333333333332 and for 2:00 1.2714285714285716. Please help.

Comment: @STACK_MIN these requests are getting less standard: Try https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rqZ5rsgKFJBKufPsxmFzFX/4 or https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rqZ5rsgKFJBKufPsxmFzFX/5

Comment: SELECT
      DISTINCT(date_trunc('hour', time - interval '1 minute')) as "time",
   AVG(data)
       OVER (PARTITION BY (date_trunc('hour', time - interval '1 minute'))) as 
FROM exercise
 time < (date_trunc('hour', now()))
order by time;

Comment: You wouldn't use distinct _AND_ a window query, you would just use a standard group by without the window function. But that is not what was requested in the original post., you wanted the data and the aggregate in-line returning 1 row for each of the raw value rows. That would have been fundamentally simpler to answer. With all the tools and exmaples posted I hope this has helped broaden your understanding of this topic.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
select avg("data") from yourtable
where "time">=(date_trunc('hour',NOW()::timestamp) - INTERVAL '1 hour')
and
"time"<=date_trunc('hour',NOW()::timestamp);
```

sqlfiddle was showing null as data gets old with time..
please check at your end.

Comment: This only provides one value, I want the value for each hour.